# PlayStore publishing from two different persons

Tags: android, react-native

I am managing a mobile application that was first published by another person and I was on my way to release the first update on my own but I couldn't.

- **Used technology** : `react-native`
- **What I did**:

1. Followed official [react-native doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) on how to publish (create keystore, configuring project accordingly, generating aab, uploading it to Google Console)
2. When I uploaded my `.aab` file, I got the following error

```
Upload failed
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: *SHA1 Key*
```

3. I understood that there is a key problem but I couldn't know what would solve it, I tried downloading the keys provided in the Google Console but that also was a dead-end !

What can I do ? Can someone explain how can two developers (or more) manage the releases of the same application ?

Comment: You have to obtain keystore file from previous developer and use the same key they have used to originally sign the app. Otherwise it's impossible to publish an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to basically have the same signing certificate which was used to upload a build in the first place and use the same certificate they have used to originally sign the app. Otherwise you cannot publish a new update for the app. if you have lost the certificate, you can contact the google team.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you ! that confirms my understanding